# Connect to an available SMTP sever using node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, smtp

I would like to integrate with a SMTP server that already exists to send mails in my react application.
I want to do this without using any smtp libraries.
Can someone guide me on where to start with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this without any library, I would check out the details of the SMTP protocol, then have a look at how the node mail libraries achieve the same result.

Here's some sample node.js code that will send SMTP messages, it would be easy to integrate your react application with the node.js code to send messages (just wrap the send function using Express perhaps)

I'm using [mail.smtpbucket.com](https://www.smtpbucket.com/) for testing it's a useful SMTP server for development, you can see any messages you send to it. For a locally hosted SMTP server, you'd use localhost and 25 as host and port respectively.

```
const net = require('net')

class SmtpSender {

    data = "";

    constructor() {
        this.socket = net.createConnection(options.port, options.host);
        this.socket.on("data", d => this.data += (d + "").trim());
        this.socket.on("error", msg => console.error("Error:", msg));
    }

    async sendCmd(msg) {
        let response = await this.write(msg);
        let [status, respMsg] = [Number(response.substr(0,3)), response.substr(4)]
        // Throw if we get an SMTP error. 
        if (status >= 400) throw new Error(`SMTP Error: ${status} ${respMsg}`)
        if (status) console.log(`${msg.trim().padEnd(40)}${status} ${respMsg}`);
    }

    write(msg, timeout = 250) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.socket.write(msg, "utf8", () => {
                this.data = "";
                setTimeout(() => resolve(this.data), timeout);
            });
        })
    }
}

async function wait(timeout) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
}

const options = { 
    host: "mail.smtpbucket.com", 
    port: 8025, 
    from: "jenny.smith@example.com",
    to: "sandra.smith@example.com", 
    subject: "Subject",
    body: "Test message"
};

async function sendTest(options) {
    let smtp = new SmtpSender();
    await wait(200);
    console.log('SendTest: Sending message\n')
    console.log(`${'Command'.padEnd(40)}Response`);
    await smtp.sendCmd('HELO\r\n')
    await smtp.sendCmd(`MAIL FROM:<${options.from}>\r\n`);
    await smtp.sendCmd(`RCPT TO:<${options.to}>\r\n`)
    await smtp.sendCmd('DATA\r\n')
    await smtp.sendCmd(`FROM:<${options.from}>\r\n`)
    await smtp.sendCmd(`TO:<${options.to}>\r\n`)
    await smtp.sendCmd(`SUBJECT:${options.subject}\r\n\r\n`)
    await smtp.sendCmd(`${options.body}\r\n`)
    await smtp.sendCmd('.\r\n')
    await smtp.sendCmd('QUIT\r\n')
}

sendTest(options);
```